# ReactJs - How to map() a Map<string, boolean>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary

Simple question I think, but cannot find a way to make it work.. I have this Map:

`public optionsCheckboxes: Map<string, boolean>;`

And in my **render()** function I would like to iterate over it:

```
renderOptionsMenu(): any {
    let test = <div className={`${style["optionsenuStyle"]}`}>
        {this.optionsCheckboxes.map((option: string, is_checked: boolean) => {
            return <div>{option} is {is_checked}</div>
        })}
    </div>
    return test;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.from` to convert `Map<string, boolean>` into `Array<[string, boolean]>`

```
renderOptionsMenu(): any {
    let test = <div className={`${style["optionsenuStyle"]}`}>
        {Array.from(this.optionsCheckboxes).map(([option, is_checked]) => {
            return <div>{option} is {is_checked}</div>
        })}
    </div>
    return test;
}
```

Example [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-water-4461y)

```
const optionsCheckboxes = new Map<string, boolean>();
optionsCheckboxes.set("Option 1", true);
optionsCheckboxes.set("Option 2", false);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from(optionsCheckboxes).map(([option, is_checked], index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {option} is {is_checked + ""}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hmm when I try, it doesn't get inside.. I put some `console.log("...");` but nothing. I even put a breakpoint and debugged manually and it doesn't get in, but I do have values

Comment: I can't say for sure what's wrong without full source code, but you can see this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-water-4461y)

Comment: Thanks for your Code Sandox, it actually provide the exact example and made me realized that i was setting my map in the wrong way at the same time... PLEASE EDIT YOUR ANSWER and add your code from your sandbox. Thanks again